# how can I do handling in nestjs when not caught

Tags: nestjs

I am using nestjs.
I have created an AllExceptionFilter.
However, once I run the post request api on the httpService and then an error is returned
nestjs will not accept the RESTful API after that.

What should I do?

■ error log

```
/Users/username/Documents/workspace/project/nestjs/src/shared/filters/custom-exception.filter.ts:29
      path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRequestUrl')
    at AllExceptionsFilter.catch (/Users/username/Documents/workspace/project/nestjs/src/shared/filters/custom-exception.filter.ts:29:25)
    at ExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters (/Users/username/Documents/workspace/project/nestjs/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:33:26)
    at ExceptionsHandler.next (/Users/username/Documents/workspace/project/nestjs/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:13:18)
    at /Users/username/Documents/workspace/project/nestjs/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:13:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

■ no try/catch point code

```
await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.post(
      url,
      {
        id: 'id'
      },
    ));
```

■ AllExceptionFilter

```
import {
    ExceptionFilter,
    Catch,
    ArgumentsHost,
    HttpException,
    HttpStatus,
  } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';
  
  @Catch()
  export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}
  
    catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
      // In certain situations `httpAdapter` might not be available in the
      // constructor method, thus we should resolve it here.
      const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;
  
      const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
  
      const httpStatus =
        exception instanceof HttpException
          ? exception.getStatus()
          : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
  
      const responseBody = {
        statusCode: httpStatus,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
      };
  
      httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, httpStatus);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an error is thrown by your endpoint, and the exception filter has an error that is triggered when attempting to handle the first exception.

As specified in the stack trace, the error is coming from: `custom-exception.filter.ts:29`, which is this line: `path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest())`

The problem is that `httpAdapter` in that line is undefined. For some reason DI isn't injecting it.

If you're using this filter globally, note the following from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters):

> Global-scoped filters are used across the whole application, for every controller and every route handler. In terms of dependency injection, global filters registered from outside of any module (with useGlobalFilters() as in the example above) cannot inject dependencies since this is done outside the context of any module. In order to solve this issue, you can register a global-scoped filter directly from any module using the following construction:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you use the above approach you won't need the `useGlobalFilters()` method.

If you want to bind this filter at the controller level, the following syntax enables DI:

```
@UseFilters(AllExceptionsFilter)
@Controller("app")
export class AppController {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in official NestJS documentation.

The docs says that we are passing already parsed httpAdapter in bootstrap function:

```
const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
```

this means that we should use not **HttpAdapterHost** type (as it follows from **AllExceptionsFilter** class in constructor) but **ExpressAdapter** type. So, in **AllExceptionsFilter** class in constructor you should point the **ExpressAdapter** type and not **HttpAdapterHost** as it is in example:

```
constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: ExpressAdapter) {}
```

end then the example code for **AllExceptionsFilter** class will work

**OR**

You can leave the **AllExceptionsFilter** class as it is in docs and just apply it to target controller using UseFilters decorator (and dont change the **main.ts** file):

```
@UseFilters(AllExceptionsFilter)
```

in this case this **AllExceptionsFilter** will be apllied only to selected contoller/endpoint